# What are the accepted naming convention for the terms "public/private keys" and "certificates"?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, x.509, terminology

Is there an accepted naming convention for referring to PKI artifacts?

There seems to be a lot of confusion with the naming of artifacts.  For example, it seems that some people refer to:

- public keys as certificates
- public keys as public keys
- certificates as public keys
- certificates as certificates
- private keys as key pairs
- private keys as private keys
- etc ..

Is there an authoritative reference or glossary that I can refer to?

Comment: Just a quick note - you may have accepted my answer, but *please* read Tom Leek's answer too. It's much more comprehensive and he's an actual cryptographer, so this kind of question is right in his ballpark.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The following** are the "accepted naming", i.e. the terms that *I* would accept:

A *public key* is a mathematical object; it is half of the cryptographic key pair. For RSA, a public key is a pair of big integers (modulus and exponent), nothing more.

A *private key* is a mathematical object; it is the other half of the key pair. For RSA, a private key is a bunch of big integers (namely *n*, *e*, *d*, *p*, *q*, *d* mod *p-1*, *d* mod *q-1* and *q<sup>-1</sup>* mod *p*, where *n* and *e* are copies of the two corresponding values from the public key).

A *key pair* is a public key with the corresponding private key.

A *certificate* is a signed object which some elements and binds them together. That's what [X.509](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) is about. Most certificates contain a *public key* (not the private key) and an *identity* (a "name") designating the owner of that key (i.e. the entity who controls the corresponding private key).

---

That being said, a lot of people use sloppy terminology and you can encounter a lot of jargon abuse. E.g.:

- For usual algorithms (everybody uses RSA), the public key is easily recomputed from the private key (with RSA, the public key is a *subset* of the private key, so this recomputing is trivial). This leads some people to talk about "key pair" when they mean "private key" or vice versa.
- Some people (in particular a substantial fraction of Microsoft's documentation) talk about "certificate" when they mean "the certificate *and* the private key corresponding to the public key which is in the certificate". [PKCS#12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_%E2%99%AF12) archive files (also known as "PFX") are usual containers for a certificate and its private key.
- Many people don't grasp the difference between a certificate and a public key, and use the two terms in a seemingly random way.
- Confusion is further enhanced when people being to talk about "public certificates" or "private certificates". Part of the problem is that games with key pairs and RSA-like algorithms are called *public-key cryptography* as opposed to "normal" cryptography, i.e. symmetric algorithms like AES. In symmetric cryptography, keys are *secret* and no key can be made public. So there is an expression: *secret key*. This term normally designates a key for a symmetric algorithm, which is a bunch of bits. But some people say "secret key" when they mean "private key", or vice versa.
- I have also encountered "digital identity", "private identity", or "digital credentials", meaning a certificate, a private key, both, or something else. Depending on who does the talking.
- There is also a notion of *secret-key certificate* which is either someone who considers "secret" and "private" to be interchangeable, or the specific case of a certificate used in some advanced "blind signature" schemes. This is research-level work, nothing standardized.

Bottom-line is that if you want to be reliably understood, then you *must* take care to define your terminology properly. Similarly, be prepared, when reading documents from other people, to encounter just about anything. Decent standards begin with a glossary which unambiguously defines the meaning of terms within the standard.

Comment: Great answer. I would add that in my experience as an engineer, it's a critical skill to listen to everyone in a meeting, identify the misuse of any technical term, and getting people to agree on the proper definition. That one skill fixes more problems than you could possibly imagine!

Comment: I like that "Confusion is *further enhanced*..." -- If your confusion is insufficient, you can *enhance* it by using terms like "private certificate".

Answer (score 4):

All three are totally distinct concepts.

A public key, in reference to any asymmetric cryptosystem, is the key which can be made available to parties that wish to be involved with you. A private key, conversely, is the corresponding private part of the asymmetric key pair that you keep secret.

A certificate is a standardised format for representing identity. The identity may contain key material, or it may just be a statement of identity signed by a secondary key. In traditional HTTPS, the certificate contains the public key of the web server, and the certificate is usually signed by a trusted 3rd party.

Answer (score 2):

The examples that you gave look quite right except when you referred private keys as key pair.

When asymmetric keys are generated they are generated as a key pair I.e. Public and Private keys. Private key should not be referred as key pair.

About certificates: if I have your x.509 certificate I can always say that I have your public key as the public key is a part of the x.509 certificate.

The one thing that I have noticed is that some people get confused between the terms 'private' and 'secret'. The private key is supposed to be kept as a secret but generally secret key is used to refer to the shared secret in symmetric key algorithms.